# How can I create and populate an HTML table using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

```js
arrayName = ["name1", "name2", "name3"];
arrayAge = [21, 18, 19];
arrayColor = ["green", "blue", "yellow"];
arrayMonth = [1, 6, 4];
```

```html
<div class='col-xs-12 col-md-3 last'>
  <div id='colunaConversaoConsultor' class="col-md-12">
    <div id="linhaConversaoConsultorTabela" class="row clearfix">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have 4 JavaScript arrays, which one corresponds to a column:

```
arrayName = ["name1", "name2", "name3"];
arrayAge = [21, 18, 19];
arrayColor = ["green", "blue", "yellow"];
arrayMonth = [1, 6, 4];
```

I have an html element like that:

```
<div class='col-xs-12 col-md-3 last'>
   <div class="col-md-12">
      <div id="table" class="row clearfix">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I need to put the elements of those arrays into my html talbe, like that:

```
|  Name | Age | Color | Month |
| name1 | 21  | green |   1   |
| name2 | 18  | blue  |   6   |
| name3 | 19  |yellow |   4   |
```

I'm trying using `getElementById("#table")` and some `array.ForEach( )` but I'm getting troubles because my arrays corresponds to columns instead of rows

Comment: why not use a for loop then and access the array values via the counter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's ony way to insert table into `html` via `javascript`. Just iterate over the arrays and create html elements with required data.

```js
const arrayName = ["name1", "name2", "name3"];
const arrayAge = [21, 18, 19];
const arrayColor = ["green", "blue", "yellow"];
const arrayMonth = [1, 6, 4];

const $table = document.getElementById('table');
$table.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', createTable());

function createTableRow(data) {
  const arr = data.map(e => {
    return `<td>${e}</td>`;
  });
   
 return `<tr>${arr.join('')}</tr>`;
}

function createTable() {
  const tableRows = arrayName.map((name, i) => {
    return createTableRow([name, arrayAge[i], arrayColor[i], arrayMonth[i]]);
  });
  
  return `
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>Name</td>
          <td>Age</td>
          <td>Color</td>
          <td>Month</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        ${tableRows.join('')}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  `;  
}
```

```css
table,
table tr,
table td {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="table" class="row clearfix"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue a while ago.
You can use this function to create this table dynamically.
All you have to do is to pass a 2D array to the function and it will create it.

```js
const data = [
["Name","Age"],
["Adam", 21],
["Samy", 28]
]
function tableCreate(data){
    var body = document.body,//Change the body element to the element that you want the table to be inserted into
        tbl  = document.createElement('table');
    tbl.style.width  = '100px';
    tbl.style.border = '1px solid black';

    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        var tr = tbl.insertRow();
        for(var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++){
                var td = tr.insertCell();
                td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data[i][j]));
                td.style.border = '1px solid black';

            
        }
    }
    body.appendChild(tbl);
}

tableCreate(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplify by mapping to one array and then use template to output.

You can tidy the HTML from this example.

```js
const arrayName = ["name1", "name2", "name3"];
const arrayAge = [21, 18, 19];
const arrayColor = ["green", "blue", "yellow"];
const arrayMonth = [1, 6, 4];

const master = arrayName.map((name, i) => ({
  name,
  age: arrayAge[i],
  color: arrayColor[i],
  month: arrayMonth[i]
}));

const template = ({name, age, color, month}) => `
  <div class='col-xs-12 col-md-3 last'>
   <div class="col-md-12">
      <div id="table" class="row clearfix">
        | ${name} | ${age} | ${color} | ${month} |
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
`

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.querySelector('.content').innerHTML = master.map(row => template(row)).join('');
});
```

```html
<div>|  Name | Age | Color | Month |<div>
<div class="content"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the data by the iteration index.

```js
let arrayName = ["name1", "name2", "name3"];
let arrayAge = [21, 18, 19];
let arrayColor = ["green", "blue", "yellow"];
let arrayMonth = [1, 6, 4];

let addRow = (...columns) => {
  let row = document.createElement('div');
  columns.forEach(column => {
    let span = document.createElement('span');
    span.textContent = column;
    row.appendChild(span);
  });
  document.querySelector('#table').appendChild(row);
};

arrayName.forEach((name, i) =>
  addRow(name, arrayAge[i], arrayColor[i], arrayMonth[i]));
```

```css
#table div {}

#table span {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="table" class="row clearfix">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
arrayName = ["name1", "name2", "name3"];
arrayAge = [21, 18, 19];
arrayColor = ["green", "blue", "yellow"];
arrayMonth = [1, 6, 4];

var tbl = document.getElementById("table");
var element = document.getElementById("table");

var i =0;

for(i =0;i<arrayName.length;i++) {
   
var row =  document.createElement("div");
  row.setAttribute("class", "row");
  row.appendChild(createElement(arrayName[i]));
  row.appendChild(createElement(arrayAge[i]));
  row.appendChild(createElement(arrayColor[i]));
  row.appendChild(createElement(arrayMonth[i]));
  tbl.appendChild(row);
            
}

function createElement(text) {
  var node =   document.createElement("div");
  node.setAttribute("class", "col-sm-3");
  node.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
  return node;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


      <div id="table" class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-3">Name</div>
          <div class="col-sm-3">Age</div>
          <div class="col-sm-3">Color</div>
          <div class="col-sm-3">Month</div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Use `table.createTHead` to create `<thead></thead>`.
- Use `insertRow(index)` to create `<tr></tr>`.
- Use `insertCell(index)` to create `<td></td>`.

```js
const data = [
  // Titles
  ["Name", "Age", "Color", "Month"],
  // Rows
  ["name1", 21, "green", 1],
  ["name2", 18, "blue", 6],
  ["name3", 19, "yellow", 4]
];

function createTable(data, id) {
  let table = document.createElement("table");
  table.setAttribute("id", id);

  let thead = table.createTHead();
  let tr = thead.insertRow(0);
  data[0].forEach((title) => {
    let th = document.createElement("th");
    th.textContent = title;
    tr.appendChild(th);
  });

  let tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
  for (i = 1; i < data.length; i += 1) {
    let tr = tbody.insertRow(i - 1);
    data[i].forEach((datum, j) => {
      let td = tr.insertCell(j);
      td.textContent = datum;
    });
  }

  table.appendChild(tbody);
  document.body.appendChild(table);
}

createTable(data, "table");
```

```css
#table,
#table td,
#table th {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```